# Windows Explorer (File explorer) freezing when interacting with zip file

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, freeze, zip

Whenever I interact (right-click, open, etc) with a zip file, windows explorer (file explorer) hangs for a couple of seconds and it's been bugging me for quite a while now. Help! Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: It is probably checking it out with the Defender software.

Comment: a similar issue with winzip and a possible solution (might work for explorer) so give it a try : http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/13/

Comment: run from an admin prompt: `wpr.exe -start GeneralProfile`, Then reproduce the issue, then run `wpr.exe -stop C:\hangwithzip.etl` Maybe you can zip and share this etl file.  If you want to try and understand it, from the MS store, download and install Windows Performance Analyzer.